# structure and function every time i run it says di returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

So everytime i run my code it says [Error] id returned 1 exit status what im doing is Inside main() function, a structure variables s1 and s2 are defined. Then, the user
is asked to enter information and data entered by user is displayed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    std::string name, course;
    int year;
    float grade;
};

void displayData(Student); // Function declaration

int main()
{
    Student s1, s2;

    cout << "Enter Full name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, s1.name);
    cout << "Enter Course: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, s1.course);
    cout << "Enter Year: ";
    cin >> s2.year;
    cout << "Enter Grade: ";
    cin >> s2.grade;

    // Function call with structure variable as an argument
    displayData(s1);
    displayData(s2);

    return 0;
}

void displayData(Student s1, Student s2)
{
    cout << "\nDisplaying Information." << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << s1.name << endl;
    cout << "Course: " << s1.course << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << s2.year << endl;
    cout << "Grade: " << s2.year << endl;
}
```

Comment: void displayData(Student s1, Student s2)
displayData(s1, s2);

Comment: ...but not really because `s2` is unused and thus pointless. also, take arguments by `const&` because copying them is pointless. also, voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: "everytime i run my code": you never get to run your code, because the linking step fails. And it doesn't say "id returned...", it says "ld returned..." Your future as a programmer depends rather heavily on appreciating why such nuances are important.

Answer (score 1):

`void displayData(Student s1, Student s2)`
does not match
`void displayData(Student);   // Function declaration`

You get a linker error: `ld` is your linker telling you he cannot find the declaration of `void displayData(Student);   // Function declaration`.

You have to change the definition to match the declaration:
`void displayData(Student, Student);`

Comment: @noob Do you understand what was wrong? It is important to understand why the error is gone

Comment: kinda understand it now, you explain it very well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your code something like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
  string name, course;
  int year;
  float grade;
  void displayData(); // Function declaration
  void readStudent();
};

int main()
{
  Student s1, s2;
  s1.readStudent();
  s2.readStudent();
  // Function call with structure variable as an argument
  s1.displayData();
  s2.displayData();
  return 0;
}

void Student::readStudent()
{
  cout << "Enter Full name: ";
  getline(cin, this->name);
  cout << "Enter Course: ";
  getline(cin, this->course);
  cout << "Enter Year: ";
  cin >> this->year;
  cout << "Enter Grade: ";
  cin >> this->grade;
}

void Student::displayData()
{
  cout << "\nDisplaying Information." << endl;
  cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
  cout << "Course: " << this->course << endl;
  cout << "Year: " << this->year << endl;
  cout << "Grade: " << this->grade << endl;
}
```

This is called Object-oriented programming which is very widely used.

And on why this is a good way of doing it is because you are using c++ and you are programming a Student `struct`.

Instead using a `class` would allow you to have all the methods related to that particular object close to the object or the class.

Now I don't know if it's intended to have the `displayData` function have two students as an argument but assuming you're learning to program, the error was from the linker which is suggesting your declaration was not found.

And in your code you're using `using namespace std;` and its purpose is to let you access the `std::cout, std::cin`, etc. as `cout, cin` respectively.